# Outlook signature distribution tools?

Tags: outlook

We are soon changing our corporate identity, and as such we will need to change our outlook signatures. However, being some 125 people, my colleague sysadmin and I don't want to go around changing these manually, and are thus looking for a good way to do this fully automated.

Most of our desktops are XP, with the exceptional few running Win7. Most run Outlook 2007, some run 2003.

Our environment is AD-centered, and most of the information will come from AD (telephone number, title, ...). 
The biggest problem I can see so far is that because we are bilingual (Dutch and French), there will be 2 versions of the signature, depending on what the person has as main language. People currently do not have anything in AD to distinguish this, but we could create a group for it, or perhaps add some sort of attribute.

A cheap if not free tool would be great. eMailSignature could probably do most, if not all, of this for us but it's a rather expensive tool costing some 1250 euro. We just want to distribute the signatures, actual "management" is less important as job titles don't change all that much.

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Manual Method: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went for eMailSignature on www.outlookemailsignature.com, everything seems to work although it looks rather hard to find the HTML code that works across all machines

Comment: I have used https://sourceforge.net/projects/gensignfromldap/ in several companies. It creates Outlook signature files from templates using AD attributes.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Exclaimer](http://www.exclaimer.com/) for a 250 user Company, pulling information from AD.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The price is similar to eMailSignature though, and a bit high for just migrating these signatures, it feels like.